# Java main class not found

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

Hi this is the first time using this site to answer any questions, so go easy on the format mistakes, also English is my 2nd language. So for my Computer Science Class we were asked to design a linked list of Strings to make a word such as l-e-t-t-e-r-s, I didn't have trouble making the classes at all except when it comes to running it on any IDE it simply cannot find the main class. I also tested a different simple hello world project to see if my IDE was working and hello world did work. Also if anyone sees anything wrong with my coding please feel free to give me feedback.

SinglyLinkedListInterface:

```
public interface SinglyLinkedListInterface<String>
{
    public void print ( );
    public void traversal ( );
    public Node getNext ( );
    public void addStringToFront (String newItem);
    public void addStringToRear (String newItem);
    public void addStringToMiddle (Node pos, String newItem);
    public String deleteFromFront ( );
    public String deleteFromRear ( );
    public String deleteFromMiddle (Node pos);
    public boolean isEmpty ( );
}
```

Node:

```
public class Node<String>
{
    public String data;
    public Node link;

    public Node ( )
    {
        data = null;
        link = null;
    }

    public Node (String newItem)
    {
        data = newItem;
        link = null;
    }

    public void setData (String newData)
    {
        data = newData;
    }

    public void setLink (Node newLink)
    {
        link = newLink;
    }

    public String getData ( )
    {
        return data;
    }

    public Node getLink ( )
    {
        return link;
    }

    public java.lang.String toString ( )
    {
        return data.toString ( );
    }

}
```

SinglyLinkedList:

```
public class SinglyLinkedList<String> implements SinglyLinkedListInterface<String>
{
    private Node head;
    private Node cursor;

    public SinglyLinkedList ( )
    {
        head = null;
        cursor = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty ( )
    {
        return head == null;
    }

    public Node getNext ( )
    {
        if (isEmpty ( ))
            return null;
        else
        {
            if (cursor.getLink ( ) == null)
                return null;
            else
            {
                cursor = cursor.getLink ( );
                return cursor;
            }
        }
    }

    private void resetCursor ( )
    {
        cursor = head;
    }

    public void traversal ( )
    {
        if (!isEmpty ( ))
        {
            resetCursor ( );

            System.out.println (cursor);
            while (getNext ( ) != null)
                System.out.println (cursor);
        }
    }

    public void print ( )
    {
        traversal ( );
    }

    public void addStringToFront (String newItem)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node (newItem);
        newNode.setLink (head);
        head = newNode;    
    }

    private Node moveStringToRear ( )
    {
        if (cursor != null) //do it only when the list is not empty
        {
            while (getNext ( )!= null);
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    public void addStringToRear (String newItem)
    {
        if (isEmpty ( ))
            addStringToFront (newItem);
        else
        {
            Node newNode = new Node (newItem);
            moveStringToRear ( );
            cursor.setLink (newNode);
        }
    }

    private Node backStringrack ( )
    {
        if (cursor != head)
        {
            Node temp = head;
            while (temp.getLink ( ) != cursor)
                temp = temp.getLink ( );
            cursor = temp;
            return cursor;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }

    //for sorted linked list
    public void addStringToMiddle (Node pos,String newItem)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node (newItem);
        cursor = pos;
        backStringrack ( );
        newNode.setLink (pos);
        cursor.setLink (newNode);
    }

    public String deleteFromFront ( )
    {
        String deleted = null;
        if (!isEmpty ( ))
        {
            resetCursor ( );
            deleted = (String) cursor.getData ( );
            head = head.getLink ( );
            resetCursor ( );                  
        }
        return deleted;
    }

    public String deleteFromRear ( )
    {
        String deleted = null;
        if (!isEmpty ( ))
        {
            moveStringToRear ( );
            deleted = (String) cursor.getData ( );
            if (backStringrack ( ) != null)
                cursor.setLink (null);
            else   //the deleted node at rear is the only node in the list
                head = cursor = null; 
        }
        return deleted;
    }

    //for sorted linked list
    public String deleteFromMiddle (Node pos)
    {
        cursor = pos;
        backStringrack ( );
        cursor.setLink (pos.getLink ( ));
        return (String)pos.getData ( ); //corrected 09172014

    }

    public Node Search1(String key)
    { while(getNext()!= null)
        {
                  if(key.equals(getNext().getData()))
                  {
                      cursor.setLink(head);
                  }


        }

    return cursor ; 
    }



}
```

Main:

```
public class String 
{
        public static void main (String [] args)
    {        
        SinglyLinkedList x = new SinglyLinkedList();
        x.addStringToFront("s");
        x.addStringToFront("r");
        x.addStringToFront("e");
        x.addStringToFront("t");
        x.addStringToFront("t");
        x.addStringToFront("e");
        x.addStringToFront("l");
        x.print();






    }

}
```

Comment: you should type the String param of the main method as java.lang.String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not call your main class `String`.

Additionally, *most* `NoClassDefFound/ClassNotFound` can be solved by simply running a clean and build.

**EDIT**

Java refers to class names by their `FQN` (Fully qualified class name), however built in language constructs are automatically recognised (such as `String` -> `java.lang.String`)

If you need to call your class `String` you will need to refer to all language (java) based instances by their FQN (assuming your `String` class is visible to all your classes, i.e. on the classpath)

Comment: and why he should not call it String ?

Comment: Wow..that worked perfectly, I don't understand how that works, could you elaborate more?

Comment: As it is bad practise, and care should be taken while using it. For a beginner, this is most likely OP's problem.

Comment: So why not explain why ? The main function need have a param java.lang.String[].

Comment: I usually never name my classes along any memory types, but our professor wanted us to have a specific class named String.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been stuck on this for 3 hours...

Comment: No problem man, I've made another update, also, if you found the answer useful, please accept it :)

Comment: Could you also explain what the difference between a " clean and build " is versus a regular build.

Comment: a `clean` removes all the previously compiled classes, and removes the `build`/`dist` directory before attempting to build again.

Answer (score 2):

Change the name of the class as String to something more appropraite to your need. String class is an inbuilt class of Java.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options either rename your class not to `String` or If you really want to use `String` as your class Name then , in main method declaration prefix the String with proper package name because java's main method expects array of type `java.lang.String`

```
public class String
{
    public static void main (java.lang.String [] args)
    {


        System.out.println("ran");


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a class 'String' defined in java.lang package which gets imported implicitly. So, you should either use fully qualified names when you are using String provided by the library or change the name of your class to something else.